# Linux script in a python module

Tags: python, nfc

I'm doing a project on automation and we are using the `MFRC522` library, but some of our equipment isn't working as intended. This has led us on an awkward detour for scripting and such. We are able to get the UID's of the `NFC` tag, and now we want to create a linux script that will reference these numbers.

The long and short of it is: is it possible to make a linux script run from a python module?

ex:

```
if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
   print "Card read UID:" +str(backData[0])+ "," + \
          str(backData[1]) +"," + str(backData[2])  + \
           ","+str(backData[3])+","+str(backData[4])
```

here is where I put the code for getting the `UID` to the file

here is where I'd like to put the code to link the linux script

Comment: There is no such thing as a “linux script”. *Linux* is an operating system (or, strictly, an OS kernel), not a scripting (or any other kind of) language.

Comment: I am aware of this, however what I am talking about is a linux program of sorts, ex: ./script, I suppose a bash script, i'm not sure on the actual terminology.

Comment: The generic term you're looking for is (most likely) “shell script”. You can run *anything* executable from *Python* with the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module (*Python* neither knows nor cares how an executable it calls is implemented), but if you can do something in a shell script, you can also do it, probably more cleanly and robustly, in *Python* itself.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll do a bit of research.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.  You can do things like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ls | wc -l', shell=True)
```

Important to note that using the shell flag presents some security concerns.  That's in the docs linked above.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it!

Comment: thank you, i'll definitely be looking into this, I would assume it might be something like subprocess.call('./script') or something, 99% chance that wont work, but trial and error is my best friend haha.